# Raycast съедает до 60 FPS, при чём выпускается 1 раз в 0.5 сек в корутине

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Имеется сцена, оптимизированная под мобильные устройства. Мне удалось добиться FPS в пределах 95 - 130 FPS. Но сегодня всё накрылось медным тазом, сразу как я добавил Raycast2D. С помощью него я делаю стрельбу бота. Он выпускает луч в сторону противника, и если луч встречает препятствие (другого бота, своего союзника) - бот не стреляет, не убивать же своего.

Бот имеет следующую структуру в инспекторе: у него 2 триггера (VoidWarDetect и VoidWarArea), пустой объект AimParent и в нём StartBulletPos, из которого, собственно, и делается Raycast.

[image: Структура бота в инспекторе]

На объекте StartBulletPos висит скрипт BotRaycast со следующем кодом:

```
RaycastHit2D[] rayHit = new RaycastHit2D[0];

private Transform myTransform;
public Transform parentPlanet;

// Объявляем ссылки на слои
private int playerPlanetLayer; // Игрок
private int enemyPlanetLayer; // Добрый бот
private int voidPlanetLayer; // Злой бот

// Объявляем ссылки на маски слоёв для Raycast'а
private int playerPlanetMask;
private int enemyPlanetMask;
private int voidPlanetMask;
private int finalMask;

private void Awake()
{
    myTransform = GetComponent<Transform>();
    parentPlanet = myTransform.parent.transform.parent; // Из объекта StartBulletPos получаем объект VoidMegaPlanet (6)

    // Инициализируем слои
    playerPlanetLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("PlayerPlanet");
    enemyPlanetLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("EnemyPlanet");
    voidPlanetLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("VoidPlanet");

    // Инициализируем маски
    playerPlanetMask = 1 << playerPlanetLayer;
    enemyPlanetMask = 1 << enemyPlanetLayer;
    voidPlanetMask = 1 << voidPlanetLayer;
    finalMask = playerPlanetMask | enemyPlanetMask | voidPlanetMask;
}

public RaycastHit2D[] RayCast(Transform target)
{
    Vector2 direction = target.position - myTransform.position; // Находим направление луча от нас к противнику
    rayHit = Physics2D.RaycastAll(myTransform.position, direction, 10.0f, finalMask); // Выпускаем луч, захватывая только объекты, входящие в маску
    Debug.Log("Планета " + parentPlanet.name + " готовит выстрел");
    for (int i = 0; i < rayHit.Length; i++)
    {
        Debug.LogFormat("The name of collider {0} is \"{1}\".",
            i, rayHit[i].collider.gameObject.name); // Выводим все затронутые лучом объекты
    }
    return rayHit;
}

public bool PauseShot(Transform target) // Если True - значит между нами и противником кто-то стоит и стрельбу надо поставить на паузу
{
    if (rayHit[0].collider.gameObject.name != target.name)
    {
        Debug.Log("Raycast will be paused because " + rayHit[0].collider.gameObject.name + " != " + target.name);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

На самом VoidMegaPlanet (6) висит скрипт GunEnemyController, который контролирует стрельбу бота, основываясь на данных Raycast'а, полученных из скрипта BotRaycast. Также у бота VoidMegaPlanet (6) есть скрипт контроллер бота, в котором метод OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) получает GameObject противника и отправляет его в GunEnemyController, одновременно включая стрельбу методом StartShoting().

Код скрипта GunEnemyController:

```
public bool fire;
public float rateOfFire; // Default = 0.5f
public Transform myTransform;
private Transform bulletStartPos;
private VoidController voidController; // Контроллер злого бота
private EnemyController enemyController; // Контроллер доброго бота
public Transform target; // Set in EnemyController or VoidController in void OnTriggerEnter2D()
private BotRaycast botRaycast;

private void Awake()
{
    myTransform = GetComponent<Transform>();
    bulletStartPos = transform.GetChild(2).GetChild(0);
    botRaycast = bulletStartPos.gameObject.GetComponent<BotRaycast>();
    if (gameObject.tag == "Void") voidController = GetComponent<VoidController>();
    if (gameObject.tag == "Enemy") enemyController = GetComponent<EnemyController>();
}

public void StartShoting() // Запускается из контроллера бота
{
    fire = true;
    StartCoroutine(ShotingLoop());
}

public void StopShoting()
{
    fire = false;
}

private IEnumerator ShotingLoop()
{
    if (fire)
    {
        bool pauseShot = false; // Инициализируем переменную, которая отвечает за паузу в стрельбе, если между ботом и его противником кто-то есть
        botRaycast.RayCast(target); // Рэйкастим в противника методом из скрипта BotRaycast
        pauseShot = botRaycast.PauseShot(target); // Проверяем, есть ли кто-то между ботом и его противником
        Debug.Log("Raycast pause status = " + pauseShot);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);

        if (!pauseShot && gameObject.tag == "Void")
        {
            voidController.RotateAim(); // Поворачиваем прицел AimParent в сторону противника
            GameObject BulletEnemyObj = PoolManager.GetObject("BulletEnemy", bulletStartPos.position, voidController.BulletRotation()); // Спавним пулю
            BulletEnemyObj.GetComponent<BulletEnemyController>().parentInitMe = gameObject; // Говорим пуле, кто её создал
            BulletEnemyObj.GetComponent<BulletEnemyController>().AutoDestroy(); // Пуля автоматически удалится через 1 сек, если не попадёт ни в кого
            Debug.Log("Планета " + gameObject.name + " сделала выстрел.");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Стрельба планеты " + gameObject.name + " приостановлена.");
        }
        if (!pauseShot && gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            enemyController.RotateAim();
            GameObject BulletEnemyObj = PoolManager.GetObject("BulletEnemy", bulletStartPos.position, enemyController.BulletRotation());
            BulletEnemyObj.GetComponent<BulletEnemyController>().parentInitMe = gameObject;
            BulletEnemyObj.GetComponent<BulletEnemyController>().AutoDestroy();
            Debug.Log("Планета " + gameObject.name + " сделала выстрел.");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Стрельба планеты " + gameObject.name + " приостановлена.");
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(rateOfFire);
        StartCoroutine(ShotingLoop());
    }
    else
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(rateOfFire);
    }
}
```

}

В итоге, пока не было скрипта BotRaycast, всё работало с 95 - 130 FPS. Сейчас же сразу как бот попадает в поле зрения противника, он активирует скрипт BotRaycast и начинает каждые 0.5 секунд рэйкастить противника и стрелять. При этом если противник 1, то отъедается около 20 FPS, если их 2 или 3 одновременно, то отъедается около 40 FPS уже. Я только что тестировал снова, на карте было 5 противников сразу и FPS состваил 35 кадров в скунду в среднем.

До появления Raycast бот стрелял даже если между ним и противником кто-то есть, при этом FPS продолжал стабильно оставаться не ниже 90 кадров в секунду, даже когда на карте было 7 ботов одновременно.

Собственно, вопрос. В чём дело? Я даже не каждый кадр рэйкастю, откуда такой спад производительности и как с этим бороться? Нужно, чтобы бот не стрелял по мешающим препятствиям и пока препятствие есть, нужно поставить стрельбу на паузу. Решение вижу только одно - Raycast. Или же есть более дешёвые операции, решающие мою задачу? Или всё таки можно исправить спад производительности? Помогите, уже не знаю, что с этим делать, всё облазил, про опитимизацию Raycast в инернете ни одного сайта, только официальная документация, советующая рэйкастить вне функции Update, дабы уменьшить кол-во выпускаемых лучей. Я это и делал корутиной. Не знаю, что делать, помогите)

Comment: Уберите множественный поиск компонентов GetComponent<BulletEnemyController>(), используйте кэширование. Это первое, что бросается в глаза для обязательной оптимизации.

Comment: Переменная rateOfFire = 0.5f и вызывается второй раз в корутине. А на счёт кэширования, это же инстант нового объекта из пула, не понимаю как закэшировать это. Пуля всегда разная же, и какая именно решает класс пула и потом методом GetObject, прямым обращением к классу PoolManager, а не к его объекту, возвращает его. Не понимаю пока как это можно закэшировать, был бы рад увидеть пример. Но и суть не в этом, незакэшированный объект не может отнимать 60 FPS же)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можешь пускать луч хоть каждый кадр 
просто распредели нагрузку так , чтобы в каждом кадре луч пускал только один противник:

```
Enemy[] enemies;   // массив противников
int enemiesCount;  // количество противников
int index;         // индекс противника для обработки    

void FixedUpdate()
{
    enemies[index].DoSomethingDifficult();
    index++;
    if(index == enemiesCount) index = 0;
}
```

это первое, 
ну и возможно лучше вместо raycastAll использовать просто raycast 
зачем тебе нужны все обьекты с которыми столкнулся луч ?? 
я думаю тебе хватит только первого обьекта, raycast как раз возвращает первый обьект , в который врезался луч, поэтому используй это , и просто проверь что это за обьект, если это игрок - стреляешь, если какойто другой обьект - не стреляешь 
ну и потом не уверен точно , но мне кажется что скорость работы луча зависит от его длины, ну можешь проверить это сам , создав простую сцену и пустив пару лучей разной длины и замеряв время работы каждого из них 
поэтому можна также попробовать разбить луч на несколько более маленьких, например на два 
и тогда в текущем кадре противник бросает первый короткий луч, в следующем - второй короткий луч, в следующем кадре - переходим к следующему противнику

Comment: спасибо за ответ. И правда, можно же не RaysactAll, а просто RayCast. Хороший совет. Но я не смог решить проблему, используя совет про рейкаст в FixedUpdate() только одним ботом. Система при таком подходе стала скакать: делаю рейкаст, FPS падает до 40 FPS, далее пока задержка в 2 секунды FPS = 80 кадров, следом второй рейкаст, и снова FPS = 40 примерно. Тормозит как и тормозил. Уменьшил длину луча в 3, без результатов. Странно это всё... Кстати, Unity версии 2019.3.0f3

Comment: Всё, проблема решена. Я поменял RaycastAll на просто Raycast и это действительно стало лучше. Тормозило из-за того, что на карте всего было 30 ботов и каждый из них выпускал рейкаст в противника, даже если он оооочень далеко от игрока. Я сделал так. что если боты вне триггера WarArea (Circle Collider 2D с radius = 60). то пусть просто толкаются, но не стреляют. А если они близко к игроку, то пусть уже стреляют. Это существенно снизило кол-во выпускаемых рейкастов и теперь если рядом 3 бота, то FPS не опускается ниже 70 кадров примерно. Спасибо @Slavik

Comment: И ещё кое что. Только что в корутине убрал первый  `yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);`  и оставил только второй `yield return new WaitForSeconds(rateOfFire);` и теперь всё стало работать вообще как часы.

Comment: ну во , хорош, но вообще странно что всего один луч так хавает производительность , тем более это даже не 3д, а 2д всего лишь